# How to correctly draw logic formation trees?

Tags: logic

I had an exam on Logic and came across a question which asked me to draw the logic formation tree for the following:

$$\exists xP(x,x) \lor Q(x) \land \neg \forall y R(x) \to x = y$$

The formula was given exactly like this with no bracketing so my first thought was to bracket everything to disambiguate terms however it did not turn out too well I think.

I drew the formation tree like this:

```
                                V
                              /   \
                          E(x)      A
                           |      /   \
                          P(x,x) Q(x)  ->
                                      /   \
                                      ¬   x = y
                                      |
                                     Vy
                                      |
                                     R(x)
```

And got a red circle on my paper telling me that the way I drew the tree was incorrect. Later did I find out that the correct way to draw the tree was this:

```
                                 ->
                                /   \
                               V   x = y
                             /   \
                          E(x)     A
                           |     /   \
                         P(x,x) Q(x)  ¬
                                      |
                                      Vy
                                      |
                                      R(x)
```

(Sorry for the poor tree diagrams; I can't seem to find a way to draw a tree in latex on SE)

I don't understand the difference between these two trees; to check whether my answer was correct I thought if I worked my way up from the bottom of the tree then I should arrive at the original formula , and this worked but it's apparently incorrect?

In my notes about drawing formation trees there are the following notes

```
Every non-atomic forula has a principal connective,which determines its overall logical 
form. You will have to learn to recognise it.
```

- $p \land q \to r$ has principial connective $\to$ . It's overall logical form is $ A \to B$
- $\neg (p \to \neg q)$ has principal connective $\neg$. It's logical form is $\neg A$.

But how do you recognise the logical form given a formula like the above? Do you always go with the weakest binding? This doesn't seem to always be the case. Can anyone tell me how I should approach this?

Comment: About *parsing* a *first-order* formula, you can see : Ian Chiswell & Wilfrid Hodges, [Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=JeUDUWYD5eQC&pg=PA164) (2007), page 164.

Comment: You can see Herbert Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&pg=PA78) (2nd ed - 2001), page 78 for the convention regarding the "omission" of parentheses (i.e.the convention about "precedence" between connectives and quantifiers).

Comment: The "fully parenthesized" formula, according to the "correct" parsing tree is : $[∃xP(x,x)∨(Q(x)∧¬∀yR(x))] → x=y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your diagram corresponds to

$$(\exists x \; P(x,x)) \lor (Q(x) \land (\neg (\forall y\; R(x)) \to x = y))$$

which makes no sense.

Multiple problems here

- quantifier for x is only on P, so other x's are dangling.
- quantifier for y is only for R, so y in $x=y$ is dangling.
- 'implies' is weaker than anything else

In a well posed notation (language) parsing should be unique. You just need to learn the rigorous rules. Always go for the weakest binding first in this case.

Comment: I sort of see what you mean here but can you tell me what would the formula look like bracketed? I'm a bit stuck with this when trying to understand the tree; does the $\exists x$ wrap only P(x,x) or not? Because of the $\lor$ I don't know what to bracket.

Comment: I think it's like this (∃xP(x,x)∨(Q(x)∧¬∀yR(x)))→(x=y) ?

Comment: Assumed that to omit the parentheses, in general, is a "bad habit", we have to note that the "standard" convention in *first-order* logic is that "¬, ∀, and ∃ apply to as little as possible" (Enderton) or that "the scope of an occurrence of a quantifier in a formula $\psi$ is the subformula of $\psi$ that starts at this occurrence" (Chiswell & Hodges). Thus, according to the convention, the "correct" reading of $∃xP(x,x)∨Q(x)∧ \ldots$ is : $(∃xP(x,x))∨Q(x)∧ \ldots$ and **not** $∃x[P(x,x)∨Q(x)∧ \ldots]$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Good point. I think that's what the "correct" solution diagram is pointing at, so they agree with you. However, I've seen rules where quantifiers is global unless there are parentheses limiting them...

Answer (score 1):

This is a late answer, but it makes absolutely no sense to separate a variable from its quantifier. So the only correct way to parenthesize this statement is

$$\exists x (P(x) \vee (Q(x) \wedge \lnot\forall y(R(x)\rightarrow (x = y)))).$$

Both formation trees given in the question are therefore quite wrong. The $\exists x$ should be the root, and the whole tree should look very very right-heavy.